# Objective-C NSDateFormatter returning arbitrary date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld %@",self.date,(long)  [self getYear],self.time];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];  
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM-dd-YYYY hh:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"date: %@",date);
```

If I **input**: **Mon, Feb-29-2016 9:00**

I get an **output** off **2015-12-21 03:30:00 +0000**

which is way off then the actual date

Comment: What is the value of `string` after the first line executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake / misunderstanding :

`YYYY` is

> Year (in **"Week of Year" based calendars**). Normally the length specifies the padding, but for two letters it also specifies the maximum length. This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. **May not always be the same value as calendar year**.

The proper specifier for the standard calendar year is lowercase `yyyy`

Comment: works! funnily i never had this issue in another similar scenario

Comment: See the *may not* in the last sentence of the quotation ;-)

Comment: okay another error now,
dateformatter converts the date the first time but not the second time, the code is the same as stated above

(lldb) po string
Tue, Mar-08-2016 0:00

(lldb) po date
2016-03-07 18:30:00 +0000

(lldb) po string
Fri, Mar-11-2016 16:00

(lldb) po date
 nil

Comment: The second date string is 24 hour mode. The specifier for that is uppercase `HH`